# Which encryption algorithm should I use for encrypting a string

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design

I have a very important string it's of around 20-40 words. I want to encrypt this string and store it online . Which encryption algorithm will be useful for me.

Comment: A string needs to be encoded using a character-encoding such as UTF-8. After that it becomes a question of what cipher could be used to encrypt a binary message and *any* secure cipher - preferably an authenticated cipher - would fit that bill.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [Age](https://age-encryption.org/) encryption tool. It uses a strong authenticated encryption algorithm internally (ChaCha20-Poly1305), with strong key derivation (HKDF-SHA256), good format construction to avoid attacks, a versioned authenticated header, etc. There are *many* concerns when encrypting beyond just what algorithm to use, a strong algorithm can be programed incompetently and result in no security (e.g. due to timing vulnerabilities).

Comment: This is assuming they want a tool rather than coding some sort of personal project, and the design of age can be criticised in several ways. However, I agree it's a good general recommendation compared to GPG.

Comment: Given the "very important" phrasing, I'd recommend they use a tool. If they want to program something, libsodium's easy box functions are a good start.

Comment: thanks wanted something like this